# Automatic update stats option in Azure Synapse Serverless pool SQL database

Tags: azure, serverless, azure-synapse

We have noticed that auto create and update statistics are enabled on some Azure Synapse serverless databases, while disabled on others. We were able to successfully enable auto create statistics using the ALTER DATABASE command. However, when attempting to enable auto update statistics, we encountered the following error:

> "Msg 15869, Level 16, State 70, Line 7 AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS is not
> supported for ALTER DATABASE."

How to resolve this issue? Any help/guidance is much appreciated!